# AZURE DATA FACTORY - The system could not find the environment option that was entered

Tags: azure, cloud, integration, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to configure a file system linked service on a self hosted integration runtime and I get the following error when testing the connection:

```
Cannot connect to [path]. Detail Message: The system could not find the environment option that was entered
The system could not find the environment option that was entered.
```

However, the IR is configured and connected to the cloud service.
Could I be missing some firewall rules? cloud or on prem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I ended up finding the answer @ https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31bc84f4-9203-4c1d-bbcd-11b0b4893ae2/unable-to-create-a-new-linked-service-file-system?forum=AzureDataFactory

"Had A similar problem - I was using the User Name such as Fred Flintstone rather than email associated with account Fred.Flintstone@live.com.  Using the email it worked."

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error if your usernam eor password is wrong. You may double check user & password you use.

Answer (score 0):

This error is also raised if the account of the "User name" assigned to the linked service does not have permission to the directory entered in the "Host" text box